# Is there a way to verify third party app credentials inside our own app without any work required by the third party provider?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, design-patterns, architecture

We have a business requirement which needs us to achieve integration for a third party provider app ex: Hubspot in our app and then poll data using webhooks. The aim is to have a generic API which will adjust according to the client integration.

I had created this diagram for a base architecture flow:

[third party app integration architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVF61.png)

During development discussions, it was mentioned that points 4 and 5 in the diagram above needs to be done by us as the app trying to integrate the third party integration.

This doesn't really make sense to me as to how we can verify credentials for a third party provider and then the third party integration will give us back a refresh token.

My question here is whether this is even viable as a solution without SSO?

Most third party app providers will just outright refuse to do this ex: Payment gateways but the client is adamant on doing it this way.

Nothing concrete yet on the coding front, stuck on how to achieve this as a PoC. One thing that comes to my mind is using AWS Cognito for SSO and somehow fetch the token.

But the webhook part is something I'm not sure about. Plus its not a given that each integration will have webhooks.